# Don't see all gradle tasks when run on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle

I am working on an `xtext` project with Gradle as a build system. I want to run `gradlew war` in Jenkins, however, it is not available for some reason. When I run `gradlew tasks` to see all the available options, it is not listed there. These are available tasks:

```
Build Setup tasks
-----------------
init - Initializes a new Gradle build.
wrapper - Generates Gradle wrapper files.

Help tasks
----------
buildEnvironment - ...
...
```

But when I run it locally on my machine there are far more tasks available:

```
Build tasks
-----------
...
war - Generates a war archive with all the compiled classes, the web-app content and the libraries.

Build Setup tasks
-----------------
init - Initializes a new Gradle build.
wrapper - Generates Gradle wrapper files.

Documentation tasks
-------------------
javadoc - Generates Javadoc API documentation for the main source code.

Help tasks
----------
...

IDE tasks
---------
...

Run tasks
---------
jettyRun - Starts an example Jetty server with your language

Verification tasks
------------------
check - Runs all checks.
test - Runs the unit tests.
```

So `war` task is clearly there and I can run it without any issues. Why Jenkins doesn't see it then. I haven't modified any Gradle files. All contain default code created with the project. I can append any Gradle file if needed, but I do not know which one might be needed. This is however main `build.gradle` file (there are more in subdirectories:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.xtext:xtext-gradle-plugin:2.0.4'
    }
}

subprojects {
    ext.xtextVersion = '2.17.0'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    dependencies {
        compile platform("org.eclipse.xtext:xtext-dev-bom:${xtextVersion}")
    }

    apply plugin: 'org.xtext.xtend'
    apply from: "${rootDir}/gradle/source-layout.gradle"
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'

    group = 'ic.ac.uk.mydsl'
    version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    targetCompatibility = '1.8'

    configurations.all {
        exclude group: 'asm'
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Image of my parent directory in git repo:
[image]

Comment: are you sure you configured web project in the wizard. if yes the war plugin will be applied to the .web project and thus war will be available in the tasks. so are you sure you have everything commited? (e,g, settings gradle)

Comment: Sorry but, I do not know what wizard is. However, I appended the image of my git repo in the post.

Comment: this looks good. but i have no idea why it should not work. i have seen this done 100s of times and it always works. => without having access to a reproducing example: no idea. => does it work with a hello world mydsl sample?

Comment: I am going to try

Comment: So I've created a new project and didn't modify anything, still 'gradlew tasks' on jenkins returns the same list, without 'war' task.

Comment: as i said: works normally. e.g. with https://github.com/cdietrich/justatest on travis

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you run `./gradlew tasks` from the same directory on Jenkins and locally? If you run the Gradle command from the root project directory, then the tasks of the root project will be shown but not any tasks of the subprojects. Your root project doesn’t seem to apply any plugins, only the subprojects do so. Consequently there won’t be any plugin-specific tasks like `war` on your root project.

Comment: I am pretty sure I do it in the same directory because I've searched my project and there is only one gradlew file so I think it wouldn't be possible to run it from different directory anyway. How can I run the tasks from subdirectories in Jenkins cuz locally it seems to find the tasks from subdirectories automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Again late to the party but found the answer to exactly this question in my case.

Problem and Solution:

settings.gradle contains the name of the module(s) to be built.
In my setup the module was written in lower case while the directory actually was camel case.
The solution is to of course either correct the directory name or the entry in settings.gradle so that the case matches.

Details:

This was my local setup.

settings.gradle

```
include ':app'
rootProject.name='MyProject'
```

Directory structure

```
MyProject
 | App
 |  | src
 |  | build.gradle
 | gradle
 | bitbucket-pipelines.yml
 | build.gradle
 | gradle.properties
 | gradlew
 | gradlew.bat
 | settings.gradle
```

You can clearly see the mismatch of the case of the app module.

My local runtime was the Git bash which is some kind of MinGW, while the pipeline was run using an android SDK image (ghcr.io/cirruslabs/android-sdk:34-ndk).
It looks like the MinGW runtime is more case-insensitive here in comparison to the android SDK image which probably is a real case-sensitive linux.